# How to recreate this type of map in Excel?

Tags: excel, maps

[image: This is the map I want to recreate.]

Above is the map I want to recreate in Excel. My data are listed below:

```
Region       People     Percentage
South       3,919,780     32.50%
Midwest     2,533,333     21.01%
Northeast   2,686,860     22.28%
West        2,919,833     24.21%
```

Can anyone please advise on how to start this in Excel? Or, will I need to use different software? I'm using Excel 2007 on Windows, for reference.

Comment: not sure if they had this in 2007, but otherwise, i don't know a way https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/01/21/excel-maps/

Comment: I don't think it will, since I don't have access to PowerView. Do you know of any non-excel solutions to this? I guess I could use R or Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in Excel, and it won't be too hard really.  I assume that you already have the map you show in an image form?

You could import the map into Excel, then insert text boxes over the different regions you have.  Then, instead of typing INTO the text box, you can use a formula to refer to a cell with a value.

Say your "South" Percentage (`32.50`) is in Sheet2, Cell C3.  Just use the formula `=Sheet2!C3` as the Text Box contents, and you'll see the text box update itself as C3 changes.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYYET.jpg)

So instead of typing `=Sheet2!C3` or whatever into the text box itself, do so in the formula bar.

If you need to add the map, I've done something like this in the past, so just Google around for SVG or other images, and use that as your background to put the input boxes over.

Comment: Thank you! That formula suggestion gets the job done. Although, it would be cool to have the map generated automatically with the numbers in it. Perhaps, that's a task for Python or R.

Comment: @GBR24 - you can definitely do that in Excel, but it's not as straightforward (or pretty) as R could probably make it.  But, FYI, [here's a site](http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2009/08/build-your-own-choropleth-maps-with-excel.html) I've used in the past as a guide on doing so...[here's a second that helped](http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2012/12/create-excel-choropleth-maps-from-shape-files.html). And, if you know VBA - you can automate it a little.